# Billing address in CiviContribution Page

Tags: civicontribute

How can I hide the billing address in the form if the box "same billing address" is checked. This should only appear when it's unchecked? 
If it's the same then it's useless to show it again, especially when filling in with a smartphone, the member needs to scroll down even more.

Can I specify this somehow ?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Screenshot CiviContribution page]

Comment: I think the billing address wasn't shown before at some point of time. It might be a bug that got introduced in civi as I can also replicate the same on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1

Comment: ok. Unchecking the box should make appear the billing fields like on any online store